# Can I travel to the UK while waiting for an ATAS certificate?

Tags: visas, uk, study, tourism

I am from Mexico and I intend to start postgraduate studies in the UK later this year. I am going to apply for an ATAS certificate this week, which means I will get it around mid october (hopefully). The problem is that I already had a flight for september 22nd because I thought I would get my visa faster (I was too naive).

Anyway, to elaborate my question a little more, can I travel to the UK as a tourist while I wait for my ATAS certificate and then come back to Mexico to get my tier 4 student visa? As far as I know, we mexicans don't need a visa to visit the UK (correct me if I'm wrong please) but I don't know if I could get in trouble for traveling as a tourist, then leave the UK and come back around two or three weeks later as a student, so any advice/help will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Are you aware that ATAS applications at this time of year can take 30, or more, working days? That could mean that it would be November before issuance. Do you already have the visa in process or do you intend to apply subsequent to receiving the ATAS?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot start my visa application until I get the ATAS

Comment: @Dukra Why would there be any difficulty in visiting as a tourist (visa-free national) if you’ve not even submitted your student visa application? Do you have a particular concern?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.